# mvc api config not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have issue for api config & Api controller. I implemented many ways but it's not work.issue is:

My Api controller:

```
 public class HomeValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public string GetFindID()
        {
            string NewID = "";
            CarrierDao DaoObj = new CarrierDao();
            NewID = DaoObj.FindID();
            return NewID;
        }

        public int Test()
        {
            int i = 10;
            return i;
        }
}
```

Here, I have to method.

and My Api Config File:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "ActionApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
              defaults: new { action = "Get" }
          );
```

Now, when i use url

http://websitedom.com/api/HomeValues/test

it's going to **GetFindID** method instead of **test**.

I also made some search on internet but not work.Kindly let me know what mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

The concept that you are applying is wrong. API controllers map to the HTTP verb not the method name. This is little different from MVC.

You can use any kind of verb such as GET, POST, PUSH, etc while making the request, actually that will depend upon the request.  And then the routing logic will pick up the method which has that verb as prefix. It wont match the name of action as you think it must be doing.

**EDIT:**

If you are looking for using your custom names for API methods then you can use attribute routing.
Please check this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 for more info. Please not that attribute routing is available in WebAPI 2 or higher.

Answer to your problem:

```
[Route("api/home/test")]
public int Test()
        {
            int i = 10;
            return i;
        }
```

Comment: ok..than if i want to call 2nd method "Test". it's also Get. thn how can i call?

Comment: Rename it to post. And Set Request type to Post. That should call it.

Comment: but i am looking 3 get methods instead of change type.

Comment: Little late to reply on this. I hope your issue got resolved, in case still pending you can check the edit.